# Where is conf/tomat-users.xml after Homebrew installation?

Tags: tomcat, homebrew, tomcat8

I just installed brew tomcat@8 and expected to see conf directory but its nowhere to be found.  I need to find tomcat-users.xsd so I can run the manager app.  I checked all the places you would expect to find it but its not anywhere I can see ...

./libexec/conf/tomcat-users.xsd

find: conf: No such file or director

I really checked everywhere including find . conf  etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it with:

```
brew ls --verbose tomcat@8 | grep users.xml
```

You will find something like:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@8/8.5.38/libexec/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```